# Process multiple files in Python with one code

Tags: python, file, csv, pandas

I'm having some trouble with my code. I want to do the following: I have about 30 csv files which I need to process and I want the result in one single csv file. So far I have the following code (sample):

```
import pandas as pd
import csv as csv

df = pd.read_csv ("file.csv", 
                  delimiter=",",skiprows=1)

datamean10=df[61:240].mean()
datamean15=df[241:420].mean()

list10=[]
list15=[]

list10.append(datamean10.clip(0))
list15.append(datamean15.clip(0))

csvfile = "C:/Users/bla/bla/list10.csv"
with open(csvfile, 'w') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(list10)

csvfile = "C:/Users/bla/bla/list15.csv"
with open(csvfile, 'w') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(list15)
```

So this code does what I want for a single file. I wrote another script to go through all the files:

```
import sys, os
for root, dir, files in os.walk('C:/Users/bla/bla/bla'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            os.system ('averagelist.py {}'.format(root + '\\' + file))
```

Needless to say this script deletes the lists again and starts off with a blank list while I want to append the results to the same list. So that the resulting files have a row of average values for each file that is processed. Can somebody tell me how to do this? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason for having two separate scripts, why don't you combine them?

Comment: just put your `os.walk` on top of with `open(csvfile, 'w') as output:` And replace `os.system ('averagelist.py {}'.format(root + '\\' + file))` by `csvfile = file `. (Or say:  `qith open(file ..) `

Comment: How do I combine them?

Answer (score 0):

This should be a working combination.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv as csv

df = pd.read_csv ("file.csv", 
                  delimiter=",",skiprows=1)

datamean10=df[61:240].mean()
datamean15=df[241:420].mean()

list10=[]
list15=[]

list10.append(datamean10.clip(0))
list15.append(datamean15.clip(0))

csvfile = "C:/Users/bla/bla/list10.csv"
with open(csvfile, 'w') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(list10)

import sys, os
for root, dir, files in os.walk('C:/Users/bla/bla/bla'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            #csvfile = "C:/Users/bla/bla/list15.csv"
            with open(file, 'w') as output:
                writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
                writer.writerows(list15)
```

Comment: It doens't really work. I want the code to read the files file by file and run the code for every file and then export one single for every list containing the information of all the files.

Comment: Open ONE output file first and append to that. Just put everything you want to do below: `if file.endswith('.csv'):` this will be executed for every "csv" file you see in the directory tree under: 'C:/Users/bla/bla/bla'.

Answer (score 0):

Just open your output files in append mode inside the inner script:

```
with open(csvfile, 'a') as output:
```

and truncate then only in master script:

```
with open("C:/Users/bla/bla/list10.csv", 'w') as output:
    pass
with open("C:/Users/bla/bla/list15.csv", 'w') as output:
    pass


for root, dir, files in os.walk('C:/Users/bla/bla/bla'):
    ...
```

But using `system` to call a Python script from another Python script is bad. I would be better to write the working part of the inner script in a function, and then use it from the outer script after importing it:

Inner script  (averagelist.py)

```
import pandas as pd
import csv as csv

def average(file):

    df = pd.read_csv (file, 
                      delimiter=",",skiprows=1)
    ...    
    with open(csvfile, 'w') as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerows(list15)
```

outer script:

```
import os
import averagelist

with open("C:/Users/bla/bla/list10.csv", 'w') as output:
    pass
with open("C:/Users/bla/bla/list15.csv", 'w') as output:
    pass
for root, dir, files in os.walk('C:/Users/bla/bla/bla'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            averagelist.average(root + '\\' + file))
```